# How to make my app receive broadcast when other applications are installed or removed

Tags: android, permissions, broadcastreceiver

I want to make an app that can receive broadcast when other apps on the device are installed or removed.

my code

in manifset:

```
<receiver android:name=".apps.AppListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

in AppListener:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class AppListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v(TAG, "there is a broadcast");
    }
}
```

but I can't receive any broadcast. I think this problem is due to app permissions, any idea?

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".apps.AppListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add the line before the intent-filter tag

```
<data android:scheme="package"/>
```

So your manifest should look like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".apps.AppListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
         <data android:scheme="package"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Am not sure about the PACKAGE_REMOVED intent in that if its actually is available.

Comment: @rup35h arg1.getDataString() will return "package:TheInstalledPackageName" just like "package:com.google.joke"

Comment: `PACKAGE_INSTALL` is useless, deprecated and never have been used by Google: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL

Comment: It did not work for me. I have multiple actions in my intent filter. Among which, PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED properly triggers my receiver's onCreate, however, PACKAGE_ADDED simply does not. My app is already in running state, I have exported="true" for the receiver and I have included <data android:scheme="package" /> as per your suggestion. Am I missing something here?

Comment: how to trigger my_app onReceive() for if any new app is installed or uninstalled even my app is not running also please help me,if app is running installed and uninstalled onreceive is triggered if app not running not listening.

Answer (score 21):

You must eliminate **android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL** as it is deprecated and no longer recommended, because it is just for the system. Everything else is perfect and I would recommend that instead of 100, put 999, the documentation does not give maximum or minimum number to use, the larger the number, the higher priority will have your receiver for that intent. Sorry for the translator. I speak and write in Spanish.
[Information](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL)

```
<receiver android:name=".apps.AppListener">
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
     <data android:scheme="package"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 9):

Great Answers, just one small thing left:

On every App update first ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED will be called followed by ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED- if you wish to ignore these events, just add it on your onReceive():

```
if(!(intent.getExtras() != null &&
    intent.getExtras().containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING) &&
    intent.getExtras().getBoolean(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false))) {

    //DO YOUR THING
}
```

This is from the docs:

> EXTRA_REPLACING Added in API level 3 String EXTRA_REPLACING Used as a
>   boolean extra field in ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED intents to indicate that
>   this is a replacement of the package, so this broadcast will
>   immediately be followed by an add broadcast for a different version of
>   the same package.
>   Constant Value: "android.intent.extra.REPLACING"

Comment: I want my broadcast to trigger event only when application is installed or uninstalled but not on when application is updated. How to handle this ?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Android 11, since direct access to all packages is restricted, there is a new permission introduced:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

This is to be used along with the accepted answer, to get the information of all the packages. For getting information about only a few packages, a <queries> declaration can be added in Manifest file, read more at [this medium article.](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9)

Answer (score 1):

from Android 11 and above, you need to use filtring as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility), and the broadcast will receive the action correctly,

```
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.myApp" />
</queries>
```

or you can use QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission, but you should know, this permission needs subject to approval to be uploaded to google play as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```