# Unable to receive ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED/ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have written a launcher - and everything works fine but I can't seem to be able to update the screen when an app was installed or uninstalled externally (using Settings, for example).

Here's my Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <action android:name="ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I did have a warning that says "Exported receiver does not required permission" (which I don't quite understand even by reading around).

In my BroadcastReceiver, the onReceive() method is not called.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("iHome", "received action!"); // replaced by refresh method
    }    
}
```

I have also try to register (in onCreate) and unregister (in onDestroy) the Broadcast receiver dynamically, but also does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: I found my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-receiving-broadcast-when-application-installed-or-removed

Answer (score 0):

Replace the action names with

```
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
```

And

```
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start, but I still did not see the Log message (which means onReceive() is not called).