# How to show message if application is going to be uninstalled in Android 4.0 or latest(not below)?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to get message or alert when we are going to uninstall the application in Android 4.0, I am getting alert message below 4.0 but not in latest.

**This is working properly in SDK 10 but not working in SDK 16 or later.**

This my BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class UninstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // fetching package names from extras
        String[] packageNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES"); 

        if(packageNames!=null){
            for(String packageName: packageNames){
                if(packageName!=null && packageName.equals("com.example.sos")){
                   // start your activity here and ask the user for the password 

                    Intent intt = new Intent(context,EmailActivity.class);
                    intt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                     context.startActivity(intt);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

In Android manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.pw.receiver.UninstallReceiver">
          <intent-filter android:priority="0">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
          </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

It is working properly below Android SDK 16 or Android 4.0 but not working in latest version.

Please help me how to solve SDK compatibility issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to receiving broadcast when application installed or removed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-receiving-broadcast-when-application-installed-or-removed)

Comment: @CharanPai Please read carefully question then comment, this question is only for Android 4.0 or later not before

Comment: If this is possible, it represents a security flaw in Android. Apps are not supposed to be able to get control when they are being uninstalled.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for replying but would you tell me how to show message before uninstalling ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in later versions of Android. It used to be possible.

> This is working properly in SDK 10 but not working in SDK 16 or later.

That is correct - the bug / feature has been fixed.

---

Update: I see @CommonsWare has left the same answer in a comment of his own:

> If this is possible, it represents a security flaw in Android. Apps
>   are not supposed to be able to get control when they are being
>   uninstalled.

Comment: thanks for replying but any possible way to get message before uninstalling ? please reply

Comment: "This is not possible in later versions of Android."