# How to know pre Uninstall of my application

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

I am using below code running background in a Service to get the pre uninstall event but it is calling for all applications, which I don't require. I want event for only my application.

Example: 
My application "A"
Other applications "B","C"....

When tries to Uninstall "A" application I want pre uninstall event.

But current code returning pre uninstall event for other applications like "B", "C".....

```
            // get the info from the currently running task
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = mActivityManager
                    .getRunningTasks(10);

            String activityName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity
                    .getClassName();

            Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + activityName);

            if (activityName
                    .equals("com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity")) {
                // User has clicked on the Uninstall button under the Manage
                // Apps settings

                // do whatever pre-uninstallation task you want to perform

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "warning!!! You are not supposed to uninstall",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (!mIntimation) {
                    startIntimate();
                    mIntimation = true;
                }
            } else {
                mIntimation = false;
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't, not for yourself.  If you could hook your own uninstall it would be a treasure trove for malware.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

[How to receiving broadcast when application installed or removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-receiving-broadcast-when-application-installed-or-removed)

Also check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED

Comment: this will receive after the application is removed. It will not solve my problem.....

Answer (score 0):

In android there is no way for applications to get itself notified that app is getting uninstalled. you cant check that your application is going to uninstall.

When the user uninstalls the app, at first the process is killed, then your APK file and data directory are deleted, along with the records in Package Manager.

You can refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) to confirm.

There's no way for your application to know that it is being uninstalled (without modifying the kernel). All files created in the data/data/your.app.package is deleted automatically upon uninstall.

Just one Alternative that I can Think of for this:

You can have another application that checks whether your first application is installed or not. If not, it can do whatever you wanted to do when App was uninstalled.