# Get Application List after Installing an Application

Tags: android

I want to get the Latest Application list after installing any application. so that I can Update my Adapter. I have Gooleplay store in My application, when user install any application then I want to add this Application in my List.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Comment: basically i am making Launcher so I need run time applications

Comment: you need to make one broadcast receiver.
Please refer below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-receiving-broadcast-when-application-installed-or-removed

Comment: Thanks  @Hiren i got your point