# Android background service stop when app data cleared from device

Tags: android

Iam working with android  background service with alarm intent for calling service after every 30 minutes.when i cleared app data from device, service stop and not working, is there any solution for that?

Comment: Could you show your code here?

Comment: this link http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Scheduler.zip is from android docs and explain how to set alarm and intent service

Comment: hii  @Grzegorz Bielański .. iam using normal service and start from main activity with also start alram intent , and also implement broadcast for when device switched off ...then again start , broadcast will fire and start service again with alarm intent

Comment: i wnna ask smthng that ...is alarm work after device data cleared ? or is it possible to forcefully again start service after app force stop or data cleared?

Answer (score 0):

When you clear the data for an app from the device setting, the app is force closed and all related `Activity`, `Service` and jobs get stopped. Clearing the data will remove any user data, databases, etc including things like account settings, persistent preferences, etc.

The next time you open the app, it is fresh and behaves in the same way it would have done if it was opened for the first time. Clearing the data should revert the application back to it's state as it was when you first installed it.

Comment: So the short answer is NO

Comment: Yes, the answer is *No*.

Comment: according to my need i will not open app again even app icon will not show, and also hide from background, only service will be  running continuously and fetch data from server and store in device ...and second app will depend on it, which fetch data from device and show ... so not possible to start service app again and again.....or open that app

Comment: How are you starting the `Service` when the app is installed for the first time?

Comment: ya sir....launching one app from another app scenario ... so first time it will be start when installed ..

Comment: In that case you can again start the `Service` when user opens the other app.

Comment: thanq sir for reply  .but  ...is there any way to..find out the condition when app forcefully stop or clear data ...like deivce boot broadcast ?

Comment: You can try listening to PACKAGE_INSTALL broadcast. Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11246479/1086930

Comment: thanks..check  from other app that service running or not...if not ...then restart...working well..