# Callback after successful installation of another app in android

Tags: android, google-play

I am using the following code to install a 3rd party app in android -

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
activity.startActivityForResult(installIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

This opens the app install page in play store. When the user taps on `install`, the app downloads and installs.

Now I want to go back to my app and perform some action as soon as the 3rd party app gets installed.

I couldn't find much help on internet and official android documentation. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an answer for that: [How to make my app receive broadcast when other applications are installed or removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-make-my-app-receive-broadcast-when-other-applications-are-installed-or-re)

But watch out: Starting Android 8, you must use registerReceiver (e.g. in a Service) and you can not register the receivers in the manifest.

Comment: I wrote the following code as you suggested -

Comment: I wrote the following code as you suggested -  `appReceiver = new AppReceiver(this);  intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);  registerReceiver(appReceiver, intentFilter);`  I am making a Log statement and displaying a Toast inside the `onReceive()` method in `AppReceiver` which extends `BroadcastReceiver`.  But nothing seems to work.

Comment: No, I am doing it in activity. Btw, I found what I was missing - `intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");`