# If My application Installed in device then after Any Application install from play store then show Notification using my application

Tags: java, android

Any insight to solve this problem will be very helpful...
Thank You in advance

Comment: You have to take some time to find your way for implementing or fixing your's feature/issue, Then if you find some issue that prevent you to complete, Here you can provide the community with what you did and the community will push you forwards to finish the task!, Have a nice day!

Comment: @KhaledLela thanks for reply me...but i trying my best i failed to search im new in development

Comment: You need your app to listen for any other apps install actions?

Comment: Yeah i just want to check if app installed successfully then just take that app name and push notification "XYZ" app installed...

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take a look around and see how to ask a proper valid question in this community.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I will Learn soon sir...Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That was possible before **Android 8.0 (API level 26)**, Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11246479/1283715)

```
<receiver android:name=".apps.AppListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
         <data android:scheme="package"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

After **android 8.0** from [docs:](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts)

> Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register
>   broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. An
>   implicit broadcast is a broadcast that does not target that app
>   specifically. For example, ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED is an implicit
>   broadcast, since it is sent to all registered listeners, letting them
>   know that some package on the device was replaced. However,
>   ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED is not an implicit broadcast, since it is
>   sent only to the app whose package was replaced, no matter how many
>   other apps have registered listeners for that broadcast.

**Workaround** by CommonsWare, [sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.10/Introspection/SAWMonitor)

> You can also use polling, setting up a JobScheduler job to check every
>   so often, asking PackageManager for what has changed in the roster of
>   installed apps via [getChangedPackages()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getChangedPackages(int)):

Comment: For who downvote, Kindly leave a comment so I can improve my answer instead of downvote without any mention about what's going wrong.

Comment: BTW, I add a comment on OP's question to help how to write a good questions,