# Detect when installation has finished in Intent using ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE

Tags: java, android, android-intent, apk

I have a launcher type application from which user can install different apps. It is working completely fine but the `apk's` from different apps just keep stacking up and taking too much space.

Is there a way that I can detect that application installation has completed when using `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)` and then I could delete the previously downloaded `apk`... after the installation has completed.

Here is some code:

```
    Intent openDownloadIntent = getOpenDownloadedApkIntent(context, file);
    try {
    context.startActivity(openDownloadIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO
    }

    private static Intent getOpenDownloadedApkIntent(Context context, File file) {

    // The type of intent to use to open the downloaded apk changed in Android N (7.0)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".utils.DownloadedFileProvider",
                file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setData(path);
        return intent;
    } else {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        return intent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks similar to post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-make-my-app-receive-broadcast-when-other-applications-are-installed-or-re

Comment: Been trying to make that work, but I am failing to recieve that broadcast, but it pointed me in the correct direction I hope so thank you.