# Keeping track of app installations initiated from another app in React Native

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, attribution

I have a situation where I would like to have an option to open App/Play store from one application (application A) to download another app (application B) and to keep track of how much installs of app B happened initiated from app A.

When thinking of a custom solution, the biggest problem I think of is providing some kind of ref to App/Play store which would be persisted until we open the app B when we can register that event.

There are some existing solutions like appsflyer, but I'm not sure how appropriate and easy to use their react native sdk is for this situation.

Would be really grateful if somebody who has done this or similar things would give suggestions on what is the best approach to tackle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at these libraries:

**Android**: https://github.com/redpandatronicsuk/react-native-check-app-install

**iOS**: https://github.com/dimapaloskin/react-native-installed-apps

You should be able to place a flag in the asyncStorage and check installed apps at every launch until you find that app B has been installed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem, as I can imagine a lot of edge cases that this doesn't cover. For example, the user could've opened the store from app A, close it, and then later install app B independently from app A, and it would still be registered as B initiated the install which is not the case. Maybe I'm missing something, could you please explain the flow in more details?

Comment: ok, I misunderstood your need. Maybe you can mix some time limited check with a listener in a broadcast receiver like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-make-my-app-receive-broadcast-when-other-applications-are-installed-or-re

Comment: otherwise, if you have control on both applications, you can use something like this in Android https://github.com/Gretchin/react-native-install-referrer