# How can I run code in the background when a new app is installed?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I'd like to run code in my app when any new app is installed. Is there a way to do this?
I'm open to methods that require the use of a foreground service or elevated app permissions.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-make-my-app-receive-broadcast-when-other-applications-are-installed-or-re

Comment: Thanks Harshal; unfortunately, apps cannot receive the broadcasts discussed in that thread in modern versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

You need make foreground service that and also make broadcastReceiver
this received

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
```

This action broadcastReceiver need to register in service